# ncurses - No output from pad

Tags: c, ncurses

Trying to get output from pad, but getting only a blank screen.

```
#include "curses.h"

int main()
{
    initscr();
    WINDOW *pad = newpad(25, 80);

    wprintw(pad, "Hello, World!\n");
    prefresh(pad, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 80);

    wgetch(pad);

    delwin(pad);
    endwin();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in a 40x80 screen, I get output (the "Hello, World!" message).  Perhaps your screen is only 24x80.  The parameters for the `prefresh` call cannot exceed the screen-size, and since you did not enable scrolling (`scrollok`), the `wgetch` hangs without displaying anything.

This example works for instance:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{   
    initscr();
    WINDOW *pad = newpad(LINES+1, COLS);

    wprintw(pad, "Hello, World!\n");
    prefresh(pad, 0, 0, 0, 0, LINES-1, COLS);

    wgetch(pad);

    delwin(pad);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So my LINES and COLS have values of 25 and 80 respectively, but to get `prefresh()` working I need to pass `LINES  - 1, COLS - 1` to it. `LINES - 1, COLS` doesn't work for some reason.